# How to auto start oracle listener on Linux with machine restart?

Tags: oracle, linux

I've a Linux VM with Oracle database serve and it gets restarted periodically and hence next time, oracle listener is not running. So I've to start it manually with following commands -

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=orcl;
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start LISTENER

sqlplus
sys as sysdba/password
startup
```

This activity I've to do every time machine is restarted.

Is there a way with which oracle listener is started along with machine start? i.e. something like windows services which gets automatically started with machine start.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered hundreds, if not thousands, of times. A simple google search turns up dozens of hits. When in doubt, refer to the official oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/strt_stp.htm#UNXAR140

As an aside, there is no reason for you to manually enter all those commands to set the oracle environment.  That is what the 'oraenv' utility is provided for.  First, as a one-time setup, make sure your database is properly listed in /etc/oratab.  Creating the database with dbca should have done this for you. Mine looks like this (the 'cat' command types the file, piping the output to 'grep -v' filters out the comment lines.

```
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$ cat /etc/oratab | grep -v ^#




cdb:/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1:N
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$
```

The format of the entry is

```
oraclesid:oraclehome:Y|N
```

Now before invoking oraenv, let's check our enviornment:

```
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$ env|grep ORA
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$
```

The 'env' command shows all environment variables. Piping the output to 'grep' allows me to show only those that contain the string 'ORA'.  And you see I have none. Also, you see that $ORACLE_HOME/bin is not in my PATH.

Now envoke oraenv. When prompted, enter the value of ORACLE_SID, as listed in /etc/oratab

```
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$ source oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? cdb
The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$
```

Now let's check the environment again:

```
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$ env|grep ORA
ORACLE_SID=cdb
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/bin
[oracle@vbol83-02 dba]$
```

And you can see that 'oraenv' set it all for me.

I take it one step further, and put that in by .bash_logon script, so that my environment is set 'automagicly" when I log on to the server:

Relevent contents of my .bash_profile:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# 3 Aug 2012 - Ed Stevens
#   - replaced hard coded settings of ORACLE_* vars with use of oraenv
#     utility.
export ORACLE_TERM=xterm
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=cdb
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
. oraenv
unset ORAENV_ASK
```

Answer (score -1):

※ Login to the system as the owner of Oracle Home.

Precaution : If you start the listener first and start the database later then register the database to the listener.
so it is recommended to plan the automatic start for both database and listener sequentially(Refer additional information).

-------------------------------------EXCERPT START---------------------------------

Specify REGISTER to instruct the PMON background process to register the instance with the listeners immediately.
If you do not specify this clause, then registration of the instance does not occur until the next time PMON
executes the discovery routine. As a result, clients may not be able to access the services for as long as 60
seconds after the listener is started.

-------------------------------------EXCERPT END-------------------------

■Reference:

SQL Language Reference(Refer REGISTER Clause)

URL : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-SYSTEM.html#GUID-2C638517-D73A-41CA-9D8E-A62D1A0B7ADB

▼ Please follow below steps to start the listener automatically when OS is restarted

※ There is no specific document with related to the command below.So I have tested the results in the in verfication environment.

Step 1: Go to the (/home/oracle) location and you can see the "bash profile" file.

Example :  $ls -la .bash_profile

Step 2: use the editor and add listener starting command statement
"$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start LISTENER_NEW" at the end of the
(.bash_profile) file.
You can see the added statement below in the (.bash_profile) file.

Example :    $ cat .bash_profile

$ORACLE_HOME : is the database software in your environment.

LISTENER_NEW : is the name of the listener created in your environment.

If you do not know the listener name, please check the file in the path below.
　
<ORACLE_HOME>/network/admin/listener.ora

Step 3: Reload the profile . Stop the listener and restart the server then you can
observe that the listener is up and running

====================Additional information==============

```
☆ Procedure to start DB and listener automatically when the OS starts: 
============================================================================
```

Step 1:  Update 'oratab' (under /etc or /var/opt/oracle) as:

```
        <SID>:<ORACLE_HOME>:Y
```

If the above part is N, edit it to Y.Where Y states that the database can be started up and shutdown using dbstart/dbshut.

```
       <SID>         : is the DB instance name of the customer's environment.
       <ORACLE_HOME> :　where Database software is installed
```

Step 2.Create the service script at root user (/etc/init.d/dbora)

※ If you using non default listener then use listener name in the script like
$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

#!/bin/bash

#chkconfig: 35 99 10

#description: Starts and stops Oracle processes

#ORA_HOME=

#ORA_OWNER=

ORA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1

ORA_OWNER=oracle

case "$1" in

'start')

su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"

su - $ORA_OWNER -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart ;;

'stop')

su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop"

su - $ORA_OWNER -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbshut  ;;

esac

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Step 3: Set script permissions:

Example : # chmod 755 /etc/init.d/dbora

Step 4:Register the Service

Example : # /sbin/chkconfig --add dbora

Step 5:Check the configuration

Example : # systemctl enable dbora

Step 6: Restart the server

Step 7: To test the startup of your database and listener, issue the following command "as root":

Example : # service dbora start (OR) # /etc/init.d/dbora start

■Reference: (Applicable to Oracle 19c also)

How to Automate Startup/Shutdown of Oracle Database on Linux (Doc ID 222813.1)

URL : https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=222813.1

---

※ You can Register the service with systemd and implement procedure to start DB and listener automatically  when the OS starts.(Doc ID 2229679.1 - Applicable to 19c also)

Step 1: Modify /etc/oratab and set the database to start automatically.

# vi /etc/oratab

:<ORACLE_HOME>:Y

```
 If the above part is N, edit it to Y.

<SID name> :   is the DB instance name of the customer's environment.
```

<ORACLE_HOME>:  Database software is installed in

Step 2: Create an environment definition file  as a root user
Write down the environment variables used by the listener and the Oracle
database when the system starts.

Example:

# vi /etc/sysconfig/oracledb

ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle

ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1

ORACLE_SID=orcl

Step 3: Create a systemd setting definition file as a root user,
　When the system starts, the database and listener
"Set it to start automatically."
Database startup service "/usr/lib/systemd/system/oracledb.service" file
like below example

//////////////////Database startup service/////////////////////////

[Unit]

```
Description=The Oracle Database Service
After = network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/oracledb 
ExecStart=<ORACLE_HOME>/bin/dbstart <ORACLE_HOME>
ExecStop=<ORACLE_HOME>/bin/dbshut <ORACLE_HOME>
User=oracle 

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Create the "/usr/lib/systemd/system/listener.service" file with settings like the
example below.
/////////////////Listener startup rvice/////////////////////////////

[Unit]
Description=oracle net listener
After=network.target

```
[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/oracledb 
ExecStart=<ORACLE_HOME>/bin/lsnrctl start <listener name>
ExecStop=<ORACLE_HOME>/bin/lsnrctl stop <listener name>
User=oracle 3

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

★ WantedBy=graphical.target supports runlevel
Please check the runlevel with the "who -r" command.

★ If you do not know the listener name, please check the file in the path
<ORACLE_HOME>/network/admin/listener.ora.

Step 4: Reload the created service settings.

Example : # systemctl daemon-reload

Step 5: Activate the created service.

Example : # systemctl enable listener.service oracledb.service

Step 6: Restart the server to verify that DB is up automatically

==================================================

■Reference:

Automatic Stop of Database (dbshut) not working in OL 7 with systemd (Doc ID 2229679.1)

URL : https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2229679.1